# Hiring a non-USA freelancer through Upwork

Tags: freelance-websites, taxes

I'm a USA business owner.

I'd like to hire a freelancer that I know from Malaysia and have the contract through Upwork as it makes payments easier on my end.

My question is:

I know that Upwork requires the freelancers that are non-USA to fill out a W8 but do I need that W8 for tax purposes and do I need to send the international freelancer a form such as a 1099?

Answer (score 4):

No - You do not need to fill out a W8 because it is for the Freelancer who will be getting payment (directly in his/her account) via Upwork. Because he/she will be earning there, it's his/her source of income, not yours.

Comment: I accepted your edit just for clarification btw She is used for both genders when you are not sure what is the actual sex of person you are referring.